пишу бота опросника на питоне и он не хочет переходить от записи user id к след действию
import telebot
from telebot import telebot
import time
import datetime
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, сегодня ты поучавствуешь в викторине')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def someone_event(message):
  connect = sqlite3.connect('elkiigiolki.db')
  cursor = connect.cursor()
  cursor. execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elkiigolki(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Nick INTEGER, Team name TEXT, name TEXT, question INTEGER, answer INTEGER)''')
  user_id = [message.from_user.username]
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO elkiigolki (Nick) VALUES(?);', user_id)

  @bot.message_handler()
  def main(message):
      bot.send_message(message.chat.id,' для продолжения введите название вашей команды и имена ее участников (одним сообщением)  ')

  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def someone_event(message):
        a = message.text
        connect = sqlite3.connect('elkiigiolki.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO elkiigolki (Team) VALUES(?);', a)


  @bot.message_handler()
  def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "вопрос второй")
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def someone_event(message):
        a = message.text
        connect = sqlite3.connect('elkiigiolki.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO elkiigolki (answer) VALUES;', a)
        time.sleep(100)

  @bot.message_handler()
  def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "вопрос второй")
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def someone_event(message):
         a = message.text
         connect = sqlite3.connect('elkiigiolki.db')
         cursor = connect.cursor()
         cursor.execute('INSERT INTO elkiigolki (answer) VALUES;', a)


         time.sleep(100)


  @bot.message_handler()
  def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "вопрос третий")
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def someone_event(message):
        a = message.text
        connect = sqlite3.connect('elkiigiolki.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO elkiigolki (answer) VALUES;', a)

        time.sleep(100)

  @bot.message_handler()
  def send_text(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "конец викторины")


bot.infinity_polling()


Так вы лишние отсупы уберите. Весь код @bot... должен быть на одном уровне, а у вас большая часть кода получилась вложенной в функцию someone_event, она считайте просто не видна никому. Причём там у вас одинаковые названия функций с теми, которые на верхнем уровне (main, someone_event). Вы разберитесь что у вас должно быть. А, у вас там вообще пять раз код повторяется один и тот же. Без толку туда код дописывать внутрь функции, там ничего не будет работать, выносите на верхний уровень.

@CrazyElf хоть и не очень корректно , но задекарированные функции можно называть одинаково, они всё равно отработают нормально. А вложенные обработчики тут используют вместо регистрации следующего шага, что каждый раз у меня вызывает вопрос - какой умник это придумал и почему за ним все повторяют?!

@Amgarak А как они отработают, если у них название одинаковое? Или декоратор их как события добавляет в обработку боту?

@CrazyElf да, так и есть. Когда скрипт инициализирует декораторы у них в мозгах происходит добавление всех задекорированных функций в список обратного вызова. Фактически задекорированные функции подписываются на события бота. А там уже название функции роли не играет. Даже имея одинаковое название функций, адреса то у них разные. Проблема возникнет только в текущем пространстве имен, если мы попытаемся сослаться напрямую на какую-то из функций самостоятельно(например передать в качестве следующего шага).
